# python to write data into table error

Tags: python, mysql

write python program to create a mysql table and insert data into this table,the program is as follows:

```
def pre_data_db_manage(type,data):
    conn = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", passwd="********", db="facebook_info",charset="utf8")
    cur = conn.cursor()


    if type == "pre_davi_group_members_data":
        is_exist_table_sql = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'fb_pre_davi_group_members_posts'"
        if cur.execute(is_exist_table_sql) == 0:
        create_table_sql = '''CREATE TABLE fb_pre_davi_group_members_posts (id bigint not null primary key auto_increment,userID bigint,userName varchar(128),userURL varchar(256),
                                    postTime varchar(128),postText text,postTextLength int,likesCount int,sharesCount int,commentsCount int,postTextPolarity varchar(64),postTextSubjectivity varchar(64))'''
        cur.execute(create_table_sql)

    r = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9]')
    for item in data:
        if "'" in item["PostText"]:
            item["PostText"] = item["PostText"].replace("'"," ")
        if "\\" in item["PostText"]:
            item["PostText"] = item["PostText"].replace("\\","\\\\")
        for i in item["PostText"]:
            result = r.match(i)
            if result == None:
                print("in re")
                item['PostText'] = item['PostText'].replace(i, ' ')
        if "nan" in item["SharesCount"]:
            item["SharesCount"] = 0
        if "nan" in item["LikesCount"]:
            item["LikesCount"] = 0
        if "nan" in item["CommentsCount"]:
            item["CommentsCount"] = 0
        if "nan" in item["PostTextLength"]:
            item["PostTextLength"] = 0
        item["PostTextLength"] = int(item["PostTextLength"])
        item["LikesCount"] = int(item["LikesCount"])
        item["SharesCount"] = int(item["SharesCount"])
        item["CommentsCount"] = int(item["CommentsCount"])

        if type == "pre_davi_group_members_data":
            insert_sql = '''INSERT INTO fb_pre_davi_group_members_posts (userID,userName,userURL,
                        postTime,postText,postTextLength,likesCount,sharesCount,commentsCount,postTextPolarity,postTextSubjectivity) VALUES
                        ({0},"{1}",'{2}','{3}','{4}',{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10})'''.format(item["UserID"],item["UserName"],item["UserURL"],item["PostTime"],item["PostText"],item["PostTextLength"],item["LikesCount"],item["SharesCount"],item["CommentsCount"],item["PostTextPolarity"],item["PostTextSubjectivity"])
            print(insert_sql)
            try:
                cur.execute(insert_sql)
            except Exception as e:
                print("insert error")
                continue
    cur.close()
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

and write call statement as follows:

```
type = "pre_davi_group_members_data"
pre_data_db_manage(type, df_list)
```

however,when execute this program, found that no data have been inserted into table:fb_pre_davi_group_members_posts,

in the mysql order line, write:

```
select count(*) from fb_pre_davi_group_members_posts;
```

the result is 0

could you please tell me the reason and how to solve it

Comment: Do yourself a big favour and take up SqlAlchemy or Django

Comment: No way to tell you why without having data (`df_list`) to test, but do you at least see the printed sql in your shell ?

Comment: Now for something totally different: __your code is fully opened to SQL injections__ (see http://bobby-tables.com/), and you make things much more painful than they have to trying to escape values manually. Use the db api the right way and it will both prevent SQL injections AND take care of proper escaping for you. See http://bobby-tables.com/python for more on this.

Comment: to bruno,I have write the insert sentence in mysql order shell,it is right,but in python program,it can not insert,why